# Python -> Pygame Window Close instatly

Tags: python

i'm follow Clear Code tutorial, and my pygame window closes instantly, i see some guys talking about identation, but i think that's ok.

```
import pygame, sys
from settings import *

class Game:
    def __init__(self):

        # General Setup
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((LARGURA, ALTURA))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Pozzani Rugby Game')
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
    def run(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()


            self.screen.fill('black')
            pygame.display.update()
            self.clock.tick(FPS)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    game.run
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call the run function like `game.run()`, if you only say `game.run` is like just mentioning the function but not invoking it.

Comment: you're welcome, it's important you learn from this kind of things, it will bite you again in the future, a way to check what could be wrong is to comment a fraction of your code and check if the behavior changes, and maybe realize that the method run is not "running" at all, or use a debugger to check how the execution of the program goes, or use print debugging, no shame in that, just add a print as the first statement in each method to know it actually ran.

Comment: Another good way to check for this sort of thing is to run a linter (like flake8 or pylint) on your code - it can spot issues like this and report them which makes it far easier to spot certain bugs.